# Reinitialize learning rate when training from checkpoint in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

What is the correct way to load a Tensorflow model from a checkpoint but reset the `learning_rate` to start from the start instead of continuing from the checkpoint?

I am using the following code for initializing the optimizer.

```
learning_rate = tf.train.polynomial_decay(start_learning_rate, self.global_step,
                                              decay_steps, end_learning_rate,
                                              power=power,name="new_one2")

opt = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate)
```

I tried to restore `var_list` from the checkpoint and return only those variables whose name does no have `Adam` so that the `AdamOptimizer` is reinitialized from the start. But this doesn't help. Here's the function I use.

```
def optimistic_restore(self, save_file, ignore_vars=None, verbose=False, ignore_incompatible_shapes=False):
    """This function tries to restore all variables in the save file.
    This function ignores variables that do not exist or have incompatible shape.
    Raises TypeError if the there is a type mismatch for compatible shapes.

    session: tf.Session
        The tf session
    save_file: str
        Path to the checkpoint without the .index, .meta or .data extensions.
    ignore_vars: list, tuple or set of str
        These variables will be ignored.
    verbose: bool
        If True prints which variables will be restored
    ignore_incompatible_shapes: bool
        If True ignores variables with incompatible shapes.
        If False raises a runtime error f shapes are incompatible.
    """
    def vprint(*args, **kwargs): 
        if verbose: print(*args, flush=True, **kwargs)
    # def dbg(*args, **kwargs): print(*args, flush=True, **kwargs)
    def dbg(*args, **kwargs): pass
    if ignore_vars is None:
        ignore_vars = []

    reader = tf.train.NewCheckpointReader(save_file)
    var_to_shape_map = reader.get_variable_to_shape_map()

    var_list = []
    for key in sorted(var_to_shape_map):
        if not 'Adam' in key: 
            var_list.append(key)

    return var_list
```

This will give me all the variables except the `Adam` ones. And than I pass the resulting list of variables to the `saver`, as mentioned below:

```
varsss = self.optimistic_restore(tf.train.latest_checkpoint(my_ckpt_dir))
b = tf.global_variables()
tf.train.Saver(var_list=b[:len(varsss)])
```

But this still doesn't help - my learning rate doesn't go back to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone else is also going through the problem.

The solution was rather simple. I just added the global_step to my polynomial_decay learning rate as a placeholder. i.e

```
custom_lr = tf.placeholder(tf.int32)
learning_rate = tf.train.polynomial_decay(start_learning_rate, custom_lr,
                                              decay_steps, end_learning_rate,
                                              power=power,name="new_one2")
```

And simply pass the learning_rate in the feed dict.

```
for step in range(0, 1000):
    sess.run(feed_dict={ custom_lr: step }
```